# Java ArrayList<>() is behaving weird

Tags: java, arraylist

I am very sure that the following code should print "YES". But it prints "NO". Is it because of the 10^9 value? When I do the same code with int[] arr, it prints "YES" (Expected). Only ArrayList<>() behaves differently. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Solution {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = 1000000000;//1e9
        int y = 1;
        int z = 1000000000;//1e9
     
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);  
        list.add(z);
    
        Collections.sort(list);
        
        if(list.get(1) != list.get(2)) 
            System.out.println("NO");
        
        else 
            System.out.println("YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare objects with `!=` or `==`. Switch it to `.equals()` and it will work.

Comment: List.get() always returns objects, you must use equals

Comment: Your primitives are boxed when added to the list.